# Exporting model as .glb and model is super reflective

Tags: materials

[image]
So I just added a bump, normal, and diffuse map to this model on the walls and floor and when I export it as a .glb it turns out super glossy. I've tried turning things up and down in the nodes in the principal BDSF but nothing seems to work? any help would be great! thank you

[image]

Comment: A normal map strength of 10 is too high. Usually, you shouldn’t have it stronger than one.

Comment: The exporter ignores the bump map. Import the .glb back into Blender and look at what the material looks like.